# How can I set a Boolean variable's value with a delay, in this React 18 app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a chat application with Firebase 9 and React 18.

I run into a problem while making use of the [OutsideClickHandler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-outside-click-handler) package.

In the `SearchUsers.jsx` component, I have a search-box:

```
import OutsideClickHandler from 'react-outside-click-handler';
export default function SearchUsers({ setIsSearch, setSearchQuery }) {

  const sendSearchQuery = async (e) => {
    if (e.target.value.length > 2) {
      setIsSearch(true);
      setSearchQuery(e.target.value);
    } else {
      if(!e.target.value.length){
        setIsSearch(false);
      }
      setSearchQuery("");
    }
  }

  const handleOutsideClick = () => {
    setTimeout(setIsSearch(false), 200);
  }

  return (
    <OutsideClickHandler onOutsideClick={ handleOutsideClick }>
      <div className="search-box">
        <form className="d-flex">
          <button className="search-button text-muted">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-search"/>
          </button>
          <input type="search" placeholder="Find people to talk to" className="search-field w-100" onFocus={() => setIsSearch(true)} onChange={ sendSearchQuery } />
        </form>
      </div>
    </OutsideClickHandler>
  );
}
```

The above sets the variable `isSearch` to `false` when the user clicks outside the search-box.

In `UsersList.jsx` I have:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { or, collection, query, limit, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../firebaseConfig";
import ConversationsList from './ConversationsList';
import UserItem from './UserItem';

export default function UsersList({ isSearch, searchQuery }) {

  const location = useLocation();
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [err, setErr] = useState(false);

  const searchUsers = async () => {

    const q = query(collection(db, "users"),
      or(
        where('firstName', '==', searchQuery),
        where('lastName', '==', searchQuery),
        where('email', '==', searchQuery)
      ), limit(10));

    try {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      const usersArray = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        if (doc.data() !== null) {
          usersArray.push(doc.data());
        }
      });
      setUsers(usersArray);
    } catch (error) {
      setErr(true);
    }
  }

  const selectUser = (user) => {
    console.log(user);
  }

  const usersList = () => {
    return users.map(user => (
      <UserItem
        key={user.uid}
        user={user}
        selectUser={selectUser}
      />
    ))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    searchUsers();
  }, [location, setUsers, searchUsers])

  return (
    <>
      {isSearch ?
        <div className="chat-users">
          {!users.length ? <p className="m-0 text-center text-danger">No users found</p> :
            <PerfectScrollbar>
              <ul className="list list-unstyled m-0 d-table w-100">
                {usersList()}
              </ul>
            </PerfectScrollbar>
          }
        </div> : <ConversationsList />
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

#### The goal

The goal is to set the `isSearch` variable to `false` upon clicking outside the search-box *with a delay*, so that I can get the selected user (in the Crome console, for now, as seen below):

```
const selectUser = (user) => {
    console.log(user);
}
```

#### The problem

There is no delay, even though I do use `setTimeout`. Before introducing the [OutsideClickHandler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-outside-click-handler) package into the app, I did get the `user` object, but not anymore. And I need it.

###### Question:

How can I get the `user` object while keeping the OutsideClickHandler package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` function expects a function as its first argument, but you're directly calling `setIsSearch(false)`. As a result it's immediately executed, without any delay. So you need to pass a function to `setTimeout`:

```js
const handleOutsideClick = () => {
    setTimeout(() => setIsSearch(false), 200);
};
```

Comment: I was using `setIsSearch` as a function. Silly me.